# Get a value of a form without $_POST or $_GET methods

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress page with usage of javascript, jQuery and PHP. It generates a QRcode out of passed values to the page. After it is generated, I extract an src of a QRcode which is in data:image/png;base64 format. The problem is in passing this string to PHP without using any methods. I need it to form a HTML formated email, which is sent when page is loaded. I am not familiar with AJAX, but I know that there is a URL() method, which can pass values to the PHP functions?

Here is a code I wrote (yes, it is redundant and untidy...):
Be sure to save it onto your device and show it when you arrive!

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="image" id="image"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Send to e-mail"></input>
</form>
[gravityform id="3" title="false" description="false"] //Hidden form with values for QRcode
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/10124121272/qrcode.js"></script>
<script>
var email = document.getElementById("input_3_1").value;
var date = document.getElementById("input_3_2").value;
var type = document.getElementById("input_3_3").value;
var id = document.getElementById("input_3_4").value;
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: "Email of buyer: "+email+"; Type of an offer: "+type+"; Date of purchase: "+date+"; ID: "+id,
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var image = jQuery('img[alt="Scan me!"]').attr('src');
jQuery('#image').val(image);
});
</script>

[insert_php]
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
$to = $_GET[email];
$image = Some magical approach to get base64 image from form name="image"
$subject = 'Subject of an email';
$message = '<html><head><body>
<h1>Hello! Here is your QRcode!</h1>
<img src=$image />
</body></head><html>'
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: Whoever downwoted, please, can I know a reason?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect that it's because the question as worded literally is nonsense.  You can't send something to the server without sending something to the server.  I think I know what you're getting at, and am writing you an answer now...

Comment: I didn't down vote but you're correct that AJAX can send data to a php script to do whatever you need.

Comment: why are  $_POST or $_GET methods forbidden?

Comment: @dandavis because I want that variable to sent automatically without user participation.

Comment: then use ajax or a hidden form, GET and POST have nothing to do with user interaction (or lack thereof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is in passing this string to PHP without using any methods.

The method/verb is a key part of an HTTP request which is required if you want to send data to your PHP script.  You **must** make an HTTP request of some sort.

You can easily use AJAX to get your data to your script.

```
$.post(
  '/yourScript.php'
  qrCodeStringData
  'text/plain'
).then(function () {
  // Do something if successful
}).catch(function () {
  // Do something if failure
});
```

Also, I get the impression that you're inventing your own data format in that QR code.  I recommend using JSON so you don't have to worry about structuring your data.  (What if someone sticks a semicolon in your data?  Suddenly your format is unusable.  Using a well known format like JSON means you don't have to deal with it.)